# How to add a colorcode to the yticklabels on a seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

I have a matrix of gene expressions vs. cells and would like to display them as a heatmap, which in itself isn't an issue. However, displaying all of the genes as yticklabels would be far too chaotic and visually unappealing. Therefore, I annotated each of the genes as belonging to a particular functional group and would like to represent each functional group as a color and have their colors shown on the heatmap, in the same order as the genes appear. Just to clarify, I would not like to group them by colors which I believe you could do using seaborn clustermap.

As such, so far I have a pandas dataframe that contains a multiindex of genes and their respective functional group, and cells.

I've searched extensively on Stackoverflow and Google for answers, without any luck. This is my first attempt at anything of the kind, so unfortunately I do not know where exactly to start.

So for sheer simplicity let's say you have the following dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame(np.array([(0,1,2),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]), columns=['C1','C2','C3'], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Gene1','Gene2','Gene3'],['A','B','A']]))
```

That would yield the following:

```
           C1  C2  C3
Gene1   A   0   1   2
Gene2   B   4   5   6
Gene3   A   7   8   9
```

Now, I can simply call `sns.heatmap(data)`to generate the heatmap. However, how can I customize it such that I get colors representing A & B rather than Gene1, Gene2, Gene3 as yticklabels? For instance, say A is blue and B is green, I want it to show the yticklabels (from top->bottom) as blue, green, blue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think I understand the desired outcome. Do you want to change the text color, such that `"Gene1"` appears in blue color? Or do you want to add another column at the start that shows pixels in the respective color? Or maybe something entirely different?

Comment: No, not the text color. It is closer to the latter. I basically want a color bar (maybe that's what they're called) representative of each functional group juxtapositioned to the heatmap. This is just a random example I got from Google, but I want the same thing as the "Category" sidebar in this image: (https://s11.postimg.cc/t4ohfiwpv/heatmap3_example.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibly solution to create a new axes left to the heatmap, which shows another heatmap based on the values of the values of the second Multiindex level.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame(np.array([(0,1,2),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]), 
                  columns=['C1','C2','C3'], 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Gene1','Gene2','Gene3'],['A','B','A']]))


cats = data.index.to_frame().set_index(0)
u, inv = np.unique(cats.values, return_inverse=True)

colors = ["navy", "limegreen", "gold"]
assert(len(u) <= len(colors))

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(len(u)+1)-.5, len(u))

fig, (sax, hax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True,
                               gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[1, data.shape[1]]))

im = sax.imshow(np.atleast_2d(inv).T, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
hax.imshow(data.values, cmap="Greys")

sax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(cats)))
sax.set_yticklabels(cats.index)
sax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False)

hax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data.columns)))
hax.set_xticklabels(data.columns)

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax = fig.add_axes([.125, .08, .1, .04]), 
                    orientation="horizontal", ticks=np.arange(len(u)))
cbar.set_ticklabels(u)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: At a first glance, this seems to be precisely what I'm after. I will study it in detail later today and get back to you with a reply on whether or not it worked for me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a solid foundation to work with. I'll just need tot adjust it to my larger scale data. It is also a good starting point for not relying so much on seaborn and rather doing it from scratch using matplotlib. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you explain why you framed the BoundaryNorm like this ````np.arange(len(u)+1)-.5````rather than just leaving it as ````np.arange(len(u))````? I cannot see a difference in terms of output. I thought that it perhaps did not include the endpoint and that you thus made the range from -0.5 to 5.5 in increments of 1 to ensure that (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) would each be mapped to a color, but that still seems to be the case for the latter.

Furthermore, is the point for using it at all to reduce computing time if the dataset is huge? Even if I remove the norm kwarg, the result is the same.

Comment: Well, yes, with only two categories, it will always match up; but is is supposed to be a general solution for any number of categories.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that I, in my actual data, have 6 categories, thereby having those ranges in particular. In which cases would it not match up? More generally, my question is if BoundaryNorm takes from 0 up to, but excluding, 1, then from 1 up to, but excluding, 2 etc, similar to how range works.

Comment: I suppose in case the colormap has more colors than you have categories.

Comment: But isn't that impossible in the above code given the assertion? I apologize if I come across as annoying, I'd just like to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, so I updated the answer with a colorbar; hopefully that makes it more clear why the norm is useful.

Comment: It does. Thanks for all the help!